Can characters with Celestial Sight see normally at all?
Basically, do you lose your normal eyes when you get your special eyes?
Codex 514:

Celestial Sight Dt 8 pts
Those with Celestial Sight do not see as mortals do. No visible light
affects their eyes. Instead, their vision is confined to the realm of auras. They see the pure auric emanations given off by life, arcana and ephemera.
Celestial Sight is an improved version of Second Sight or the spell Magesense. These abilities show a cloudy, distorted window to the other side, whereas Celestial Sight sees clearly and without impediment.
With this trait, one can see the auras of spellcraft. The obstacle to detect a spell cast is 6 minus the spell obstacle. If the Ob is zero, the spell is seen outright. Celestial Sight grants the ability to use the Aura Reading skill. Lastly, Celestial Sight counts as Observation and suffers no obstacles for darkness. Weather can affect Celestial Sight, though.

Emphasis mine.

Luke Crane wrote on the official Burning wheel Discord server:

Official answer is No, they do not see normally. 

Whether one wants to go by Luke's way of seeing Burning wheel or not is one's own choice, of course.

Yes, you're now perceiving the way magic interacts with things instead of perceiving the way light interacts with them.
However, this isn't very likely to create issues for you not being able to distinguish things by magesight that could easily be distinguished by normal sight. Materials and dyes have variant interactions with magic the same as they do with light, so unless something has been deliberately engineered to confound magesight you're liable to see some point of difference. (Or perhaps the GM has thrust you into a Barrier Peaks scenario, presenting you with materials made with no consideration for magesight at all.)
Though there's also no reason for the new vistas your celestial eyes see to correspond with mortal colors, so when your tinkerer asks for the naphtha he keeps in a green bottle there's going to be some fun confusion and maybe a discussion about labels.
And then there's the question of what you see when you gaze at the vault of heaven. Black as pitch, a riot of distant color, or perhaps the forms of gods and mythic heroes the astrologers think they see?

As much as I love the flavor in this answer, it doesn't beat Word of God.
